# How to connect my clockDivider into this verilog program with Quartus II

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, quartus

Code:

TestBench.v:

```
// ============================================================
//
// Traffic light tester module.
//
// We clock the device as usual, supply reset, and eventually "push
// the walk button" to activate the traffic light.
//
// ============================================================

// `timescale 1 ns / 1 ns

module TestBench;

   reg  clk;     // Clock into the FPGA
   reg  walk;    // A button that causes the walk light to go on
   reg  reset;   // The reset line to your design

   wire green;   // The green light on Dodge Street
   wire yellow;  // The yellow light on ...
   wire red;     // The red light on ...
   wire go;      // The walk light for the pedestrian
   wire stop;    // The "don't walk" light

   // Here is your FPGA chip
   Traffic yourChip( reset, clk, walk, green, yellow, red, go, stop );
   // Provide clocking to the FPGA
   always
      begin
      #10 clk = ~clk;
      end


   // Start up code.
   initial
     begin
    clk = 0;
    walk = 0;
    reset = 1;
    #100 reset = 0;
     end

   // Eventually we want to "push the walk button" which causes the
   // traffic lights to cycle yellow, red, then back to green.
   // Also, we want to stop the sim at some point too. 
   initial
     begin
    #1000 walk = 1;
    #100  walk = 0;
    #100000 $stop;
     end

endmodule // QuasiTestBench
```

clockDivder.v:

```
module clockDivider(
    input wire clock, 
    input wire reset, 
    output wire dividedClk
    );

reg [127:0] counter;

always @(posedge clock or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset == 1)
            counter <=0;
        else
            counter <= counter + 1;
        end
    assign dividedClk = counter[127];

endmodule
```

Traffic.v:

```
module Traffic( reset, clock, walk, green, yellow, red, walkLight, handLight);
input wire reset;
input wire clock;
input wire walk;

output reg green, yellow, red, walkLight, handLight;

reg[2:0] state;
reg[3:0] count;
//we want some kind of state machine here.
//let's define some states
parameter s0 = 0  //green
    , s1=1         //yellow
    , s2=2;         //red 
reg[3:0] timeButtonPushed;

//clockDivider myClock(clock, reset);

always @(posedge clock or posedge reset)
    begin
            if (reset == 1)
                begin
                    state <= s0;  //default to green light on reset.
                    handLight = 1;
                    green = 1;
                    timeButtonPushed = 0;
                    count <= 0;
                end
            else
                case(state)
                    s0:
                        begin
                            if(walk == 1)
                                begin
                                    //compute 10s timeout before switch to yellow
                                    //requires us to capture some info about time button pushed
                                    timeButtonPushed = count;  //record time button was pushed
                                end
                            else
                                if(timeButtonPushed == (count - 10))  
                                    begin
                                        state = s1;  //We've reached countdown state set light to yellow.
                                        green = 0;
                                        yellow = 1;
                                    end
                            count = count + 1;
                        end                 
                    s1:
                        begin
                            if(timeButtonPushed == (count - 15))  //We've reached timeout for yellow light.
                                begin   
                                    state = s2;  //move to red state
                                    handLight = 0;
                                    walkLight = 1;
                                    red = 1;
                                end
                            count = count + 1;
                        end
                    s2:
                        begin
                            if(timeButtonPushed == count - 45)
                                begin
                                    state = s0; //move back to green state
                                    red = 0;
                                    walkLight = 0;
                                    handLight = 1;
                                    green = 0;
                                    timeButtonPushed = 0;
                                end
                            count = count + 1;
                        end             
                    default: state <= s0;
                endcase

    end

endmodule
```

I've tried to instantiate the clockDivider in the TestBench, and I've also tried to instantiate it in Traffic.v attempting to insert it in between the clock and the input clk wire in Traffic.v

Ideally I'd like a solution that shows me the correct way to wire the clockDivider properly, however if there are other ways--even if hack-ish to get it done I'd appreciate it.

I've also tried forgetting clockDivider.v entirely and replaced the clock code with this:

```
 reg [127:0] counter;
        always
         begin
            if(reset == 1)
                counter <=0;
            else if(counter == 126)
                assign clk = ~clk;
            else
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end
```

But that too appears to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your sample instantiation, you aren't connencting any signal to the dividedClk output. As such, it's hard to see what you're trying to use it for. You're allowed to omit connections, but you need the delimiting commas. Try: `clockDivider myClock(clock, reset,);`

Secondly, generating a clock with logic is poor design - you'll have major issues with timing. Logic signals can't be properly loaded onto the clock tree network, so you can get a large clock skew as a result. Instead, use your counter as an enable signal to any "slower" registers and use the global clock, or make use of a PLL/DLL to generate a new (slower) clock signal.

As an example of the first:

```
reg enable;
reg [127:0] counter;
parameter NUMBEROFCYCLES = 100;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (reset) enable <= 0;
    else if (counter == NUMBEROFCYCLES) enable <= 1;
    else enable <= 0;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (reset) counter <= 0;
    else if (counter == NUMBEROFCYCLES) counter <= 0;
    else counter <= counter + 1;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (reset) <<reset some signals>>
    else if (enable) <<change some signals>>
    else <<signals <= signals>>
end
```